# JOGL display using Buffer

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have 3 `FloatBuffers` - vertices, normals and colors which contain what the name suggests. I also have an `IntBuffer` to keep track of the indexing.

The data looks correct, but I'm having trouble displaying it. I just see a blank canvas. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm guessing something is being overlooked in `init()`, `display()`, `reshape()` and `dispose()`. Can anyone tell me if you find something glaringly wrong in the code below, and why you think nothing is being displayed?

```
  @Override
  public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .2f, 0.9f);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LESS);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_NORMALIZE);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL2.GL_CCW);
    gl.glCullFace(GL2.GL_BACK);
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
    if (viewMesh) {
        gl.glPolygonMode(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_LINE);
    } else {
        gl.glPolygonMode(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_FILL);
    }

    glu = new GLU();

    // Build the VBOs
    VBO = IntBuffer.allocate(4);
    gl.glGenBuffers(4, VBO);
    vertVBOID = VBO.get(0);
    normalVBOID = VBO.get(1);
    colorVBOID = VBO.get(2);
    indexVBOID = VBO.get(3);

    // vertices
    int vsize = sd.verts.capacity() * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT;
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertVBOID); // get a valid name
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vsize, sd.verts, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // reset

    // normals
    int nsize = sd.normals.capacity() * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT;
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalVBOID);
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nsize, sd.normals, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // colors
    int csize = sd.colors.capacity() * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT;
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVBOID);
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, csize, sd.colors, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    int isize = sd.indices.capacity() * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_INT;
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, isize, sd.indices, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // sd.verts = null; // copy of data is no longer necessary, it is in the graphics card now.
    // sd.colors = null;
    // sd.normals = null;
    // sd.indices = null;
} 

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluLookAt(45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    gl.glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    gl.glRotatef(rot, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glTranslatef(-sd.tr_x, -sd.tr_y, -sd.tr_z);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalVBOID);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVBOID);
    gl.glColorPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertVBOID);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, sd.indices.capacity(), GL2.GL_INT, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbind it

    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

}   

    @Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    double fov = (Math.PI / 4.0);
    double zmm = Math.abs(sd.min_z - sd.max_z);
    camdist = (zmm / 2.0) / Math.tan(fov / 2.0);

    h = (h == 0) ? 1 : h;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(camdist, w / (float) h, 0.1f, 1000.0);
}




    /**
 * Initilaize graphics
 */
public void initOGL() {
    profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    caps = new GLCapabilities(profile);
    caps.setHardwareAccelerated(true);
    canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    canvas.requestFocusInWindow();
    getContentPane().add(canvas); // add to the frame
}


    @Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}
```

Comment: You should avoid deprecated OpenGL, unless you really need it

Comment: You should replace glu = new GLU() by GLU.createGLU(gl). You might have problems if you use an unimplemented feature later whereas GLU.createGLU(gl) will create an instance of GLUgl2 in your particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One clear problem is in the draw call:

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, sd.indices.capacity(), GL2.GL_INT, 0);
```

`GL_INT` is not valid for the *type* argument of `glDrawElements()`. The only valid values are `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. So the call needs to be:

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, sd.indices.capacity(), GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Anytime you have a problem with OpenGL code not working as expected, make sure that you call `glGetError()`. With the call from your code, you should immediately get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

Also, your perspective setup code looks somewhat suspicious. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do there, but even just the naming suggests a possible misunderstanding:

```
glu.gluPerspective(camdist, w / (float) h, 0.1f, 1000.0);
```

The first argument of `gluPerspective()` is the field-of-view *angle* (in degrees), not a distance.

Comment: @Retro Koradi - Thanks for bringing to notice about the GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT.  I changed that and it still didn`t work. So, did some digging around and found that along with not using GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, there was another issue. I was not clearing the depth bffer in display. Here is what I had to do - gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); Also, changed the var name camdist to fovy, what is being calculated is the fov.